# Setting range of colors in pcolormesh

Tags: python, matplotlib

In `matplotlib`'s `imshow()`, the optional arguments `vmax` and `vmin` set the range of the colorbar.

Instead, in `matplotlib.pyplot.pcolormesh`, they seem to rescale the values plotted and leave the colorbar intact.

I want to create a series of plots using pcolormesh with a fixed colorbar range, that corresponds to say `[0.0,0.5]`, i.e. the minimum color should be at `0.0` and the maximum at `0.5`. Additionally, I want the two edges of the colormap to be at `[0.0,0.5]`, respectively.

I'm using:

```
thetas=[-4.86946861 -4.55530935 -4.24115008 -3.92699082 -3.61283155 -3.29867229 -2.98451302 -2.67035376 -2.35619449 -2.04203522 -1.72787596 -1.41371669 -1.09955743 -0.78539816 -0.4712389  -0.15707963  0.15707963  0.4712389 0.78539816  1.09955743  1.41371669]
radii=[[ 0.],[10.]]
values=[[0.00049802 0.0008128  0.00177386 0.00426617 0.01010776 0.02224737 0.04396539 0.07626507 0.11427899 0.14629945 0.15897023 0.14629945 0.11427899 0.07626507 0.04396539 0.02224737 0.01010776 0.00426617 0.00177386 0.0008128 ]]
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, subplot_kw={'polar':True})
ax.pcolormesh(thetas, radii, values,vmin=0.0,vmax=0.5,cmap='cool')
```

But the darkest color of the image is not magenta but the middle value between cyan and magenta.

Answer (score 4):

I think I figured that out:

```
# plot data on a ring
vmin,vmax = 0.0,0.5
norm = mpl.colors.Normalize(vmin=vmin, vmax=vmax)
mesh = ax.pcolormesh(thetas, radii, values,norm=norm, **kwargs)

# add colorbar
cb=fig.colorbar(mesh,norm=norm)
```